# Subselect dependent on first select value

Tags: mysql, subquery

I wish to do a select of all data matching a particular id.  I would also like to return a selection of all data matching the `alt_id` field in the first select.

This example works fine for the main query of two tables and their data based on the contact_id I feed it, in this case '1':

```
SELECT e_contacts.*, e_credentials.*
FROM e_contacts, e_credentials,
WHERE e_contacts.contact_id = '1' AND 
e_credentials.contact_id = e_contacts.contact_id
ORDER BY e_contacts.contact_id
```

However, one of the fields in `e_contacts` is called `alt_contact_id` (wife or friend) which when holds a value, requires I get both contacts data.

So, I would like to have a second row of data returned for that `alt_contact_id`'s data which exists in the same table.  In other words we'll be requerying the same select statement but feeding it `e_contacts.contact_id = alt_contact_id` found in the first select (if `alt_contact_id` has a value of course).

This is the table structure:
[image: Table structure]

I'm completely uncertain how to accomplish it.

Comment: I have updated the image associated with this at the same address:  http://www.compumatter.com/subquery.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 subqueries, one joining with the `contact_id` and another joining with the `alt_contact_id`. Then `UNION` them and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT cont.*, cred.*, 'main' AS contact_type
FROM e_contacts AS cont
  JOIN e_credentials AS cred
    ON cred.contact_id = cont.contact_id
WHERE cont.contact_id = 1

UNION ALL 

SELECT cont.*, cred.*, 'alternate'
FROM e_contacts AS cont
  JOIN e_credentials AS cred
    ON cred.contact_id = cont.alt_contact_id
WHERE cont.contact_id = 1

ORDER BY contact_id ;
```

If you want this for all contacts, just remove the two `WHERE` clauses.